# Minimize L1 Norm with Matrix Linear Equality Constraint

Tags: python, julia, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

I need to minimize L_1(x) subject to Mx = y.

x is a vector with dimension b, y is a vector with dimension a, and M is a matrix with dimensions (a,b).

After some reading I determined to use scipy.optimize.minimize:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):     #L_1 norm objective function
    return np.linalg.norm(x,ord=1)

constraints = [] #list of all constraint functions
for i in range(a):
    def con(x,y=y,i=i):
        return np.matmul(M[i],x)-y[i]
    constraints.append(con)

#make constraints into tuple of dicts as required by scipy 
cons = tuple({'type':'eq','fun':c} for c in constraints)

#perform the minimization with sequential least squares programming
opt = minimize(objective,x0 = x0,
                        constraints=cons,method='SLSQP',options={'disp': True})
```

First, 
what can I use for x0? x is unknown, and I need an x0 which satisfies the constraint M*x0 = y: How can I find an initial guess which satisfies the constraint? M is a matrix of independent Gaussian variables (~N(0,1)) if that helps.

Second, 
Is there a problem with the way I've set this up? When I use the true x (which I happen to know in the development phase) for x0, I expect it to return x = x0 quickly. Instead, it returns a zero vector x = [0,0,0...,0]. This behavior is unexpected.

Edit:

Here is a solution using cvxpy** solving min(L_1(x)) subject to Mx=y:

```
import cvxpy as cvx

x = cvx.Variable(b) #b is dim x  
objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.norm(x,1)) #L_1 norm objective function
constraints = [M*x == y] #y is dim a and M is dim a by b
prob = cvx.Problem(objective,constraints)
result = prob.solve(verbose=False)

#then clean up and chop the 1e-12 vals out of the solution
x = np.array(x.value) #extract array from variable 
x = np.array([a for b in x for a in b]) #unpack the extra brackets
x[np.abs(x)<1e-9]=0 #chop small numbers to 0
```

Comment: (1) scipy.minimize would not be my first pick (2) Why should x0 satisfy the constraints? It's not needed to be feasible. (3) There is a problem: L1-norm is non-smooth and you are using a solver assuming smoothness. I did not check for other problems. (4) The core-question here: do you know there is a solution ```Mx=y``` (is this guaranteed in your task)? If yes: you can use a LP-formulation, if not and you want a proxy like ```min |Mx-y|```, you could use a QP/SOCP-solver and weight the l1-component of the objective much more heavily compared to the error of ```|Mx-y|```.

Comment: For the `x=[0,0...]` return would be useful to know whether `opt.success` was True or False.

Comment: @sascha thanks for the reply. In reply to your points 
1) I solved the problem using cvxopt package instead,|
2) I thought scipy.minimize would require the first guess to satisfy the constraint
3) I see that the problem with L_1 norm is significant! the derivatives don't exist at points. I'm curious how cvxopt handles it 
4) And existence.. as for mathematical guarantee, that's a tricky problem. It seems to exist so far! Thanks again. The LP objective method is intuitive and I'm sure that would work -- probably that's what cvxopt does.

Comment: cvxopt just solves other problems. It's never a NLP-problem there, which assumes two-times diff. For LP/QP/SOCP, this is irrelevant, when in standard-form (meaning: there is no abs-function to put into the objective; this needs a special formulation). What cvxopt uses depends on which function you used. In general those are all interior-point methods, heavily leaning to general conic-optimization. But there is special-treatment of LPs, but only if called as LP.

Comment: I don't think you are using cvxopt. cvxopt (solvers) != cvxpy (DCP-based modelling-framework). And the default-solver should be ECOS, not cvxopt, which is not even a default-requirement (not necessarily installed). And more important: cvxpy probably treats this as SOCP; even it would be possible to be solved as LP. This is of course  slower and less robust. There are newly introduced reductions, but well... there is a lot to do here (if improvements are needed). But that's not much for StackOverflow's comment-section.

Comment: sorry about that! fixed the import line sasha-- you're right. For now SOCP seems good enough for the application

Comment: You can also solve this easily with numerical methods. Probably faster for large scale problems.

Comment: what is the definition of `b` in beginning of your cvxpy example? i.e. `b = ?`

Comment: Long time ago now @Quetzalcoatl but maybe it's `M.shape[1]` per "M is a matrix with dimensions (a,b)" in the question statement. Maybe not though.

Answer (score 0):

The Proximal Gradient based methods are very efficient solving such problem.

Let's formulate the problem (Used $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{M}, ; \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{b}$:

[image]

Where $\delta$ is the indicator function for equality with $\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{b}$.

What's needed is the projection operator to the set of constraints.
It is defined in [Linear Least Squares with Linear Equality Constraints - Iterative Solver](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596362).

The calculation per iteration is dominated by solving a linear system of size `(m x m)` where the matrix $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
This can be optimized by pre calculating the factorization of the involved matrix.

I implemented both a vanilla Proximal Gradient and Accelerated (FISTA style):

[image]

The above shows the objective value of the optimization along the iterations in dB. The reference is solving the problem using a convex solver (`Convex.jl`).

The runtime for those methods was leas than 1 [Sec] which can greatly improved by optimizing memory and factorizations.

The Julia code is available at my [StackOverflow Q49787068 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `StackOverflow\Q49787068` folder).

**Remark**: It is better to add acceleration to the process (FISTA style). It will make convergence much faster.

**Remark**: Another alternative is to formulate the problem as linear programming. See [Formulate L1 Norm Minimization with Linear Equality Constraints (Basis Pursuit / Sparse Representation) as Linear Programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639716).